# Actually show .php at the end of the file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do the exactly opposite of actually hiding the .php extension.

So if a user access my website:

example.com/test-folder/test.php

And the link looks like "example.com/test-folder/test" he'll be redirected to the .php one.
I wanna show the .php in the link. Currently I managed to get the link working using this .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

But however if I write in the browser just example.com/test-folder/test page works just fine and it doesn't add .php at the end of the link.

I found a solution so if anyone is wondering:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [R=301,L]
```

However now got into another problem. If I access it like [www.example.com/test-folder/test](http://www.example.com/test-folder/test) it works just fine but if I do it without the www. it redirects me to example.com/example.com/test-folder/test.php